# Change background color on textview dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

i'm having an edit button which is connected to this method. In this method i want to make the textView editable and change the background. The problem is the background do not seem to change. Why is that?

## ViewDidLoad

```
self.aboutText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.aboutText.delegate = self;
self.aboutText.editable = NO;
```

## method

```
-(IBAction)editField:(id)sender {

    self.aboutText.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.aboutText.editable = YES;



}
```

Comment: It looks like all is ok for me. I've tested this code and it works. Did you link IBOutlet to your text view?

Comment: what's the superView(of backgroundColor) of textView.

Comment: Make sure your outlet is connected. Also, can you post a screenshot of your view?

Comment: i've connected everything. what u want a screenshot of the storyboard ViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the issue was i only did set the action and not the target.

All i did was set the target to self.

sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

//.h file

```
@interface AddEntryViewController : UIViewController<UITextViewDelegate>{}
```

//.m file

```
  //viewDidLoad

  _aboutText.delegate = self;

 //add the following method

-(void) textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
      [textView setTextColor: [UIColor blackColor]];
}
```